# Bubbling event is not called

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am studying WPF. Infollowing the example, there is something I don't understand.

In the example below, tunneling event handlers are called, but I am curious about the reason why all bubbling event handlers are not called.

```
<ScrollViewer PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" <!-- called -->
              MouseWheel="ScrollViewer_MouseWheel">  <!-- not called -->
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox
                PreviewMouseWheel="ListBox_PreviewMouseWheel" <!-- called -->
                MouseWheel="ListBox_MouseWheel" <!-- not called -->
                VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ListBox` contains a `ScrollViewer` that handles the [`MouseWheel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmousewheel?view=net-5.0) event in order to scroll its content by setting [`e.Handled = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled?view=net-5.0) in the corresponding event args. [Event handlers up the chain are not called then](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/marking-routed-events-as-handled-and-class-handling?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). This also applies to other variants of items controls that feature a scroll viewer like `ListView` or `DataGrid`.

> When you set the value of the [`Handled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled?view=net-5.0) property to `true` in the event data for a routed event, this is referred to as "marking the event handled".
>
> **[...] handlers added in XAML or the common signature of AddHandler are not invoked in response to a routed event where the event data is already marked handled.**

However, at least when adding routed event handlers in code, [you can also use handled events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/marking-routed-events-as-handled-and-class-handling?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#when-to-mark-events-as-handled).

> You must go through the extra effort of adding a handler with the `handledEventsToo` parameter version ([`AddHandler(RoutedEvent, Delegate, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.addhandler?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.AddHandler);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0)) in order to handle routed events that are marked handled by earlier participants in the event route.

For example, you can define an `x:Name` for your `ListView` to be able to access it in code-behind.

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
```

Then you can register the event e.g. in the constructor. The last parameter of the [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.addhandler?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.AddHandler);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) method is set to `true`, so that already handled events will still invoke the registered event handler.

```
MyListBox.AddHandler(MouseWheelEvent, (MouseWheelEventHandler)ListBox_MouseWheel, true);
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`PreviewMouseWheel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmousewheel?view=net-5.0) event instead if it fits your requirements.

Comment: thank you very very very much! Hard to understand wpf but your answer is very helpful to me